# Serial console over GSM - Are there such devices?

Tags: console, serial

I just lost a server by restarting the network interfaces.

Then i got the following idea:

A small GSM device with an RS232 connector

I want to connect the serial console to the device, and in case the server gets unreachable i could call it by phone and get full access to the serial console

So here comes the question:
 are there such devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. Check out Digi's range of products - you probably want the [Digi Connect WAN](http://www.digi.com/products/cellulargateways/digiconnectwanfamily.jsp). I've used these at colos for backup/last resort connectivitiy. They're not particularly cheap though.